# Think this question should be migrated to another site? Think again

Tags: bug, flags, custom-flags

Today, I got this while flagging a post:

[image: flag text includes the words "moved to"]

> Think this question should be migrated to another site? Please first check that it is clearly-written and on-topic for the site you're recommending. If you aren't an experienced member of that site, please take some time to read their help center first, rejected migrations are frustrating to both askers and the good people on the site who must reject it. Thanks!

So... This is the reason we don't get computers to think for us.

I understand the sentiment here.  By identifying suspect keywords, you hope to provide some Just-In-Time guidance.  I'm all in favor of such guidance; however, there are (at least) three pr0blems with this particular approach:

1. This is an answer, not a question.
2. A potential migration was mis-identified.
3. It is the job of moderators to assess these requests.  If bad migration requests are being submitted to other sites through the "in need of moderation" flag, that is the fault of the moderators, not the user.

Comment: Now I'm very curious about which regex/other logic identified that message as a migration request. The only trigger words I can think of is _moved to_ but just using that would be very error-prone.

Comment: @ErikA I suspect it's "moved". Or "moved to". It *might* be slightly more involved, though - if the length of the text is compared to the suspected move request, then "moved to" is about 12% of that text. Not *big* but it's not insignificant. But I suspect it's just keywords.