# Tried to flag as plagiarism, hit invisible character limit. Tried again, was told to not recommend unclear questions for migration

Tags: bug, status-completed, plagiarism

Two things I noticed when trying to [flag something as plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423749/6083675):

- The second text box has an invisible 500 character limit. There's no warning that I was approaching a limit, nor that I passed it. The [button was just suddenly disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3u5x.png). I even checked to make sure I wasn't randomly flag banned despite having no recent declines! (Note: The first text box doesn't seem to have a character limit.)
- In the second text box I had the words "move to" and I got the message below, which is nonsensical in context. Why does it talk about "this question" when I was flagging an answer? Why would anyone use a *plagiarism* flag if a question should be migrated? If I did decide to suggest migration, do you really think the mods want me using a plagiarism flag? It made me almost think that my flag wouldn't be accepted (same as [Think this question should be migrated to another site? Think again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393864/6083675)):

  > Think this question should be migrated to another site? Please first check that it is clearly-written and on-topic for the site you're recommending. If you aren't an experienced member of that site, please take some time to read their help center first, rejected migrations are frustrating to both askers and the good people on the site who must reject it. Thanks!

  No thanks! Unless there's large numbers of people abusing the plagiarism flag for this, we shouldn't have this message pop up.

Bottom line: You can't just copy all the validation from the "In need of moderator intervention" onto the plagiarism flag.

Comment: Possibly related: [It appears that reports about plagiarized content cannot contain the word "duplicate"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424101/2821954)

Comment: The button is dimmed while disabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fine fine... I guess we could let you all know what the limits are for these fields. The plagiarism flagging options now have a character counter attached to them to let you know the limits!

[image]

[image]